# При ответе на запрос сервлет выдает текст в формате HTML без стилей CSS

Tags: java, servlet

Ниже представлен сам сервлет. Метод `getHTML()` возвращает `String`, который содержит в себе HTML разметку для нужной страницы. Саму разметку читаю из файла.

```
@WebServlet("/")
public class HTTPServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        try {
            resp.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
            String requestURI = req.getRequestURI();
            Page page = new MainPage(requestURI);

            out.println(page.getHTML());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Пример HTML разметки ниже. В ней я ссылаюсь на отдельный файл со стилями CSS.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Some title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" media="all">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Welcome to this page</h1>
    </header>

    <section>
        <p>Some section</p>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

И когда получаю ответ от сервера, вижу страницу с моей структурой, но без стилей. Они почему-то не подтягиваются. Но когда просто открываю через браузер HTML файл - стили видны. Подскажите в чем проблема? Или если это нормальное поведение, тогда прошу подсказать, каким другим путем выдать полноценную страницу со стилями?  Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Откройте консоль браузера нажмите «обновить страницу» и посмотрите какие ошибки там есть

Comment: @AlexeyTen в консоли пусто, но зато увидел предупреждение о неверном типе ответа. Видимо потому что я указываю "text/html" в resp.setContentType(), а пытаюсь еще и text/css впихнуть, проблема наверняка в этом. Но тогда как мне выдать корректный ответ клиенту?

Comment: Пропишите полный путь в css файлу. Не "styles.css", а `http://localhost:port/path/to/styles.css`. И смотреть нужно не вкладку Console, a Networking (в хроме).

Comment: @notaProgrammer Пробовал прописывать разные пути и по вашему шаблону в том числе. Если пишу в файле HTML путь `"styles.css"` или `"http://localhost:9713/forum/logging/styles.css"`, то в консоли выдает одно и то же предупреждение: `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:9713/forum/logging/styles.css"`. Если прописываю любой другой путь, то в консоли выдает ошибку: net::ERR_ABORTED 404.

Answer (score 0):

В общем да, браузер требует, чтобы тип был именно формата `text/css`. Добавил строчки:

```
 if (requestURI.contains("styles.css")) {resp.setContentType("text/css");}
```

Все работает.